# SPI - different implementation / timing

Tags: spi, esp32

I'm a little bit confused. I'm running the same code on a ESP32 (Adafruit Huzzah32) and an Arduino (SparkFun Pro Micro). It works on the ESP32 but not on the Arduino.
Are there different API implementations?
It seems that the timings are not the same. The Arduino does not have the gaps between the bytes.

[image: spi clock timing]

Comment: Maybe the other side you didn't mention is a problem. There is possibility it needs more time to prepare result (before you start sending dummy bytes). But as you didn't mention what is the other side, nobody knows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not waiting for results. The 2 '0's are just attached to make it more clear. I'm asking because i'm wondering why there are no gaps between the bytes ...

Comment: should there be wider gaps? ... the logic analyzer doen not appear to need wider gaps

Comment: No, but my SPI module seems not to understand the commands if there are not any delays. The second picture shows the same command without any delays between the bytes. My main question is, why does the ESP32 have delays and the Arduino does not? and how can i fix this without rewrite the SPI commands?

Comment: the speed is not the same

Comment: I've checked the speeds. the arduino sends with 125MHz but i need 80kHz. I didn't look at it because i've set the spi settings `SPISettings _spiSettings( 80000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0 )`.  I played around with `SPI.setClockDivider()` but i cant achieve such a low rate. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI